# How to get custom markers on google maps from my database in my website?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an hotels search web site using codeigniter(php) framework, in  this website when a user enter a location in location field the search page should display hotels in that location both in list and map view something like below image
[image]

List can do in any way, but how to do the map view? These hotels list will come from my database, i need some suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: you need the coords of the location  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for your comment, after a research in google i found how to add particular location coords to my db but what i want is how to fetch these locations from db while user search for a particular location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the location (lat, lng) inside  proper columns table in db

Client side you can use  the getBuonds for obtain the coords of the actual area showed  in map

```
aNorth     = actLayer.mlwObj.googleMap.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(); 
aEast      = actLayer.mlwObj.googleMap.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(); 
aSouth     = actLayer.mlwObj.googleMap.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(); 
aWest     = actLayer.mlwObj.googleMap.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
```

using ajax you can send this coords to you server and use these coords 
as min and max lat,  and as min and max lng for a query select that retrieve all the point inside the bound

```
    "SELECT your_lat, your_lng FROM your_table
    WHERE your_lat  between $yourMinLat AND $yourMaxLat
        AND your_lng between $yourMinLng  AND  $yourMaxLng;""
```

the result of the query  contain all the coords of the points you are looking for
eventually you need some other textual infos for you hotels

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to get hotels in and around given lat,lng not in between them can you give any suggestion.

Comment: I can not understand the difference .. your problem is finding hotels in an area or finding the area ???????

Comment: it's like difference " between 5 & 7 and in and around 5 & 7 ". I mean in between we get 6 but in, in and around we get 4,5,6,7,8 like that.

Comment: Also after your  comment  I can not understand the difference ... this is a geographics problem not a set Theory problem .. you can expand the area as you need  that the answer  return ever the content  of the area.    so you you need the hotels in a  area you can use a buond ... otherwise if need find an area you need  geolocation

Comment: thanks for your comment finally i got the query. i was confused previously.